# MS Access Parameter Query- How do I select multiple values when entering a parameter?

Tags: drop-down-menu, parameters, ms-access-2010

I have an Access DB that a couple reports point to. The reports are driven by an ID field in a fact table that brings in dimensional data via joins on dim tables. I initially set up the query that the reports are based on to prompt a start and end parameter for the ID field so that the reports would be a selection of how ever many sequential ID's that the report would need. It turns out that the reports can often times be based on non-sequential ID values, which means I need to be able to pick and choose the ID values in the parameter prompt.

Is there any way to do this in MS Access? An example would be like the parameter prompt displays a multiple selection dropdown window full of the ID values in the facts table (like clicking the filter button on a column in a table), or something similar to the calendar window if you're picking dates. Or maybe having a series of prompts for each ID that needs to be picked.

Ideas?

Edit: Although I'm not using Oracle it seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456230/prompt-user-to-enter-single-multiple-or-all-values-in-oracle-select-query?rq=1) has a possible solution.

2nd Edit: So I think I'm just trying to mirror something like the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM FactTable
WHERE [ID] in ([IDprompt])
;
```

where [IDprompt] is the parameter and the user could enter `("0001", "0011")` to get those 2 ID's. I tried this and several variations but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [a good solution](http://www.fabalou.com/Access/Queries/MultipleParameters.asp) after doing some more searching. Utilizes some VBA to parse out the input in the parameter box.